# How to configure PostgreSQL clustering (Active/Active) in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How to configure clustering (active/active) in PostgreSQL 9.1 ?  My current configurations are listed below:

RAM : 8Gb,
O.S : Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,
CPU : 4

Comment: Why are you using an outdated an unsupported Postgres version?

Comment: Actually in my company, we r using postgresql 9.1. So i need to configure according to that only. If u have any suggestion, plz share

Comment: Even i am ready to upgrade the PostgreSQL version.

Comment: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/when-to-use-postgres-bdr-or-postgres-xl/

Comment: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-9-1-end-of-life/

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a multimaster PostgreSQL solution (one where you can modify data on either node, and the modification is replicated to the other node), there is no built-in solution yet.

You can use extensions like [2ndQuadrant's BDR](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/bdr/) (but that requires a modified PostgreSQL server) or proprietary solutions like EnterpriseDB's [xDB Replication Server](https://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products-overview/xdb-replication-server-multi-master).

There is also the open source fork [Postgres-XL](http://www.postgres-xl.org/) which provides a different solution.

Comment: Is there any software in PostgreSQL, like Oracle RAC available in Oracle ?

Comment: Or what are the cluster softwares that are available in PostgreSQL?

Comment: There is nothing like Oracle RAC for PostgreSQL, and probably never will be. Shared storage is a performance bottleneck and a single point of failure. I wrote all the existing solutions I know into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use open-source database sync software symmetricDS for PostgreSQL Active Active replication setup.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [SymmetricDS](https://www.symmetricds.org/), an open source product that allows you to configure your Postgres instances in an active/active configuration.

A good guide on how to do this can be found [here](https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/a-guide-to-building-an-active-active-postgresql-cluster).